# How do I choose data structures in F#?

Tags: list, f#, deedle

I have a csv file which has almost 10000000 rows ,the structures like this:

```
date , code , ret
2001-01-01,000001,0.1
2001-01-01,000002,0.01
2001-01-02,000001,0.05
2001-01-02,000002,0.02
```

The fields "date" and "code" are only one key.  I want to subset the file quickly, like this

```
subset(code='000001')

date , code , ret
2001-01-01,000001,0.1
2001-01-02,000001,0.05
```

or

```
subset(date='2001-01-01')

date , code , ret
2001-01-01,000001,0.1
2001-01-01,000002,0.01
```

How should choose the right data structures so that it works efficiently?

Comment: I don't think it's F#-specific problem. You need some kind of dictionary (probably two, one to get quick lookup by date and another one to get it by code). In F# it would be `map` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353686.aspx. You'd have to load the entire file into memory to do that. You could also load it into a DB, apply indexes on both code and data and query that table.

Comment: thanks very much.I could use two dictionary to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the CSVTypeProvider from the F# Data project:
https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html

You could use this as the base data structure to easily parse the data into a more optimized data structure for quick access as @MarcinJuraszek describes.